Http Connection Management In Spring Cloud Gateway / Reactor Netty
We use Spring Cloud Gateway (Spring Boot 2.0) to route(POST) request to different external customer REST endpoint (along with filters).
Most of the time routing is ok in production, only certain times we are facing an exception (PrematureCloseException) in POST in case where there is a long gap (say 30 min plus) between messages (for a customer/route that uses spring OAuth2 filter for token before submission).
Tried multiple attempts to replicate scenario locally/lower env, still no success.
To look for possible config change/fix (maxIdleTime etc), trying to understand how Http connection management works in Spring Cloud Gateway, which in turn uses Reactor Netty Client? As per documentation (https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/1.1.19/reference/index.html) Netty Client uses connection pool (with defaults config until overridden), so when different request/messages are being posted to Spring Cloud Gateway for routing, are separate http connection opened and managed in pool for each "routes", to be used again for next message to be routed to same configured "route" and so on?
For Example If we have 3 routes defined in Spring Cloud Gateway for 3 customers

Route 1 - Customer 1 - endpoint 1 (abc.com/submit)
Route 2 - Customer 2 - endpoint 2 (xyz.com/submit)
Route 3 - Customer 3 - endpoint 3 (123.com/submit)

In this case, will Netty Client maintain 3 unique sets of "connection" in pool for each customer/route to serve incoming next set of messages ?
Any help/explanation will help in resolving the issue. On side note, can anyone comment on down side of disabling the connection pool (degrade in performance etc)? Thanks

Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I seem to be facing the same issue.


For Example If we have 3 routes defined in Spring Cloud Gateway for 3 customers
Route 1 - Customer 1 - endpoint 1 (abc.com/submit)
Route 2 - Customer 2 - endpoint 2 (xyz.com/submit)
Route 3 - Customer 3 - endpoint 3 (123.com/submit)

Spring Cloud Gateway will maintain 3 connection pools, every pool is per remote peer (a combination of a hostname and its associated port number)
If you decide to disable the connection pool then connection establishment, DNS resolution, TLS handshake etc. will be done on every request.

that is very helpful. So with that understanding, I believe more research is needed to identify the underlying netty client usage (if used in the first place) in spring 'OAuth2AuthorizedClient' ,that i am using in filter for OAuth token generation. As i understand the netty client used in Spring Cloud Gateway is different  instance than  the one used in OAuth client. Will keep posted

If you do not change the default ConnectionProvider then all http clients in one JVM will share this ConnectionProvider.

thanks once again, i think our app / implementation became challenging with competing "WebClient".         1) For regular HTTP Post (outside gateway)   2) Used by Spring Cloud Gateway  3) (Possibly) used by OAuth2AuthorizedClient.
I tried to atleast separate our the first one by passing customer connection provider , now trying to separate out 2 and 3. First trying to dig into how OAuth2AuthorizedClient is implemented and WebClient used in it (if at all)

Violeta Georgieva - is there any option to have logging enabled to see more insights in connection management by webclient/cloud gateway (like how may connection are opened, how many are idle, how many eligible to be evicted etc)? We are still struggling with config values for maxlifeTime, maxIdleTime etc

You can enable reactor.netty.resources logger to DEBUG.

The problem we identified in the end, is that the default elastic pool that is used by Spring Cloud Gateway (SCG) was keeping connections open for longer than the remote (without sending keep-alive packets which disabled by default in Netty), and the remote was silently closing them due to inactivity. When a new request was coming in to SCG, it was picking up a connection, trying to put data through it and only then realising the connection had been closed by remote, resulting in the above error.
There are a few things you can do. The simplest is to set spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.pool.max-idle-time to something lower than your remote (that might take experimentation). With that setting, Netty will close the connection proactively if there is no traffic on it.
Another option is to enable keep-alive packets on Netty. Sending keep-alive packets should keep the remote connection alive so in theory you prevent the silent closing, but you still rely on the remote so I would say this is suboptimal. I haven't done that but it ought to look something like this.
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClient.create()...


and a HttpClientCustomizer will probably have to be involved. You can then implement the equivalent of the max-idle-time as well with the use of Netty's "IdleStateHandler" in one go. Keep in mind though that with enough traffic the max-idle-time will never kick in, and with not enough traffic the occasional tcp handshake is not that much of an issue, so there is probably a reason why it's disabled by default.
A final thing to consider is that there might be other reasons why this happens, for example the sudden death of the remote. So what you also want to do is in any case is set automatic retries on your routes if that error pops up.
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/appendix.html
